# opencv with a complicated Makefile

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile

I got quite a peculiar problem going on that I just can't wrap my head around. I tried a lot to no avail (see later).

I'm trying to build a project using `make` that contains some added OpenCV functionality which relies on the BEACLS reachability code that already contains OpenCV functionality in the "back-end". The goal is to do some standard polygon operations on a contour of a 2D matrix. As such, I wish to use the `findContours` method. The problem is that the following code snippet:

```
// TEMPORARY TEST FOR STACKOVERFLOW
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("test.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::findContours(image, contours, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

compiles in both a little test environment and my larger project, but it only completes the findContours in the test project (no issue with `imread` in the larger project).
The same is true for the actual code snippet I am interested in:

```
std::vector<beacls::FloatVec> tmp_target(1);
tmp_target[0] = this->targets[i];

boost::multi_array<FLOAT_TYPE, 5> target_array = vectorToMultiArray(tmp_target, this->g);
cv::Mat target_array_2D = convert2DToMat(project_to_xy(target_array, this->g, 0, {0.,0.}));

cv::Mat binary;
cv::threshold(target_array_2D, binary, 0, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

std::cout << "Before conversion, type: " << binary.type() << std::endl;
binary.convertTo(binary, CV_8UC1);
std::cout << "After conversion, type: " << binary.type() << std::endl;
// std::cout << "Binary_converted: " << binary << std::endl;

// ORIGINAL CODE
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::findContours(binary, contours, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

Again, creating `cv::Mat`, and calling `threshold` and `convertTo` do not lead to any problems, it is the `findContours` function that throws a segfault.
Yesterday when I tried, it kept complaining about a wrong type being given to the `findContours` method (while I explicitly converted the type to what the error indicated, something I still do here with `convertTo`) while now it just segfaults (I did clean builds also yesterday, I'm more confused than I already was...).

For the test environment, I use the `Makefile`

```
COMPILER_FLAGS = -frounding-math -fopenmp -std=c++0x
# CGAL_FLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --cflags CGAL)
# CGAL_LIBS = $(shell pkg-config --libs CGAL) -lgmp
# opencv
OPENCV_LIBS = $(shell pkg-config --libs opencv)
OPENCV_FLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --cflags opencv)

EXEC=crender

all: main.o
    g++ -fPIC main.o -o $(EXEC) $(OPENCV_LIBS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS)

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp $(OPENCV_FLAGS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) -o main.o
```

While for the real larger project, I use the very convoluted but correct (before actually adding the `OpenCV` methods in the code) and unchanged `Makefile`

```
GPU_ON = N
VISUALIZE_ON = Y
GUI_ON = N
FILESYSTEM_ON = N
STATIC_ON = N
PROFILE_ON = N
FMA_ON = Y
USER_DEFINED_GPU_DYNSYS_FUNC_ON = Y
OPTIMIZE = 3
DEBUG_MODE = N
WARNING_ON = Y
SINGLE_PRECISION_ON = Y
FILE_DUMP = 1
CHUNK_SIZE = 0
USE_CUDA = 0
NUM_OF_THREADS = 0
NUM_OF_GPUS = 0
USE_LAST_DERIV_MIN_MAX = 0
USE_USER_DEFINED_GPU_DYNSYS_FUNC = 1
MODEL_SIZE = 0
USE_TEMP_FILE = 0
NVCC = /usr/local/cuda-11.6/bin/nvcc
ARCH = $(shell uname -m)
PWD = $(shell pwd)
INSTALL_DIR = $(HOME)/BEACLS/beacls/builds
MATIO_DIR = $(INSTALL_DIR)
MATIO_LIB_DIR = $(MATIO_DIR)/$(ARCH)/lib
MATIO_INC_DIR = $(MATIO_DIR)/include

UNAME = $(shell uname)
ifeq ($(UNAME),Darwin)
    HOSTCC_DIR = /usr
    HOSTCC  = $(HOSTCC_DIR)/bin/clang++
    OPENMP_ON = N
else
    HOSTCC  = g++
    OPENMP_ON = Y
endif


BEACLS_DIR = $(INSTALL_DIR)
BEACLS_INC_DIR = $(BEACLS_DIR)/include
BEACLS_LIB_DIR = $(BEACLS_DIR)/$(ARCH)/lib
MODULE_DIR = $(MATIO_LIB_DIR):$(BEACLS_LIB_DIR)

ifeq ($(UNAME),Darwin)
    TIME = /usr/bin/time
endif
ifeq ($(UNAME),Linux)
    TIME = /usr/bin/time -v
endif

ifeq ($(UNAME),Linux)
    GOOGLE_PERF_LIB = libprofiler.so.0
    CPUPROFILE_FREQUENCY = 100
endif

ifeq ($(GPU_ON), Y)
    CPP = $(NVCC)
    LINKER = $(NVCC)
    AR = ar
    HOST_COMPILER   ?= $(HOSTCC)
    NVCCFLAGS += -arch=sm_52 -maxrregcount=64
    NVLDFLAGS += -arch=sm_52 -maxrregcount=64
    NVCCFLAGS += -ccbin $(HOST_COMPILER)
    NVCCFLAGS += -lineinfo
    NVCCFLAGS += -DWITH_GPU
    NVCCFLAGS += -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L /usr/lib
    NVCCFLAGS += -D_FORCE_INLINES
else
    CPP = $(HOSTCC)
    LINKER = $(HOSTCC)
endif

CFLAGS   += -std=c++14 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -g -march=native

###################################
# Add additional include paths here
CFLAGS  += -I.
###################################


ifeq ($(FMA_ON), N)
    CFLAGS  += -mno-fma
endif
ifeq ($(UNAME),Darwin)
    CFLAGS += -fno-common
    CFLAGS  += -I/usr/local/include
    LDFLAGS += -L/usr/local/lib -lstdc++
endif

LDFLAGS  += -g

ifeq ($(STATIC_ON), Y)
    LDFLAGS += $(BEACLS_LIB_DIR)/libhelperOC.a
    LDFLAGS += $(BEACLS_LIB_DIR)/liblevelset.a
    LIBS    += $(BEACLS_LIB_DIR)/libhelperOC.a
    LIBS    += $(BEACLS_LIB_DIR)/liblevelset.a
else
    LDFLAGS += -L$(BEACLS_LIB_DIR) -lhelperOC -llevelset
    LIBS    += $(BEACLS_LIB_DIR)/libhelperOC.so
    LIBS    += $(BEACLS_LIB_DIR)/liblevelset.so
endif

# display LDFLAGS so we know what it is set as
$(info LDFLAGS is $(LDFLAGS))

ifeq ($(UNAME),Darwin)
    LDFLAGS += -L$(MATIO_LIB_DIR) -lmatio -lz -lhdf5
endif
ifeq ($(UNAME),Linux)
    LDFLAGS += -L$(MATIO_LIB_DIR) -lmatio -lz -lhdf5_cpp
endif
CFLAGS += -I$(MATIO_INC_DIR)

ifeq ($(SINGLE_PRECISION_ON), Y)
    CFLAGS += -DSINGLE_PRECISION
endif

ifeq ($(USER_DEFINED_GPU_DYNSYS_FUNC_ON), Y)
    CFLAGS += -DUSER_DEFINED_GPU_DYNSYS_FUNC
endif

ifeq ($(PROFILE_ON), Y)
    ifeq ($(GPU_ON), N)
        CFLAGS += -pg
        LDFLAGS += -pg
    endif
endif

ifeq ($(DEBUG_MODE), Y)
    CFLAGS += -g
endif
ifeq ($(OPTIMIZE), 0)
    CFLAGS += -O0
endif
ifeq ($(OPTIMIZE), 1)
    CFLAGS += -O1
endif
ifeq ($(OPTIMIZE), 2)
    CFLAGS += -O2
endif
ifeq ($(OPTIMIZE), 3)
    CFLAGS += -O3
endif

ifeq ($(WARNING_ON), Y)
    CPPFLAGS += -Wall -W
endif

ifeq ($(FILESYSTEM_ON), Y)
    CFLAGS  += -DFILESYSTEM
    LDFLAGS += -lstdc++fs
endif

ifeq ($(VISUALIZE_ON), Y)
    ifeq ($(GUI_ON), Y)
        CFLAGS  += -DVISUALIZE_WITH_GUI
    endif
CFLAGS  += -DVISUALIZE_BY_OPENCV
CFLAGS  += $(shell pkg-config --cflags opencv)
LDFLAGS += $(shell pkg-config --libs opencv)
OPENCV_LIB_DIR  += $(shell pkg-config --libs opencv | sed s/"-lopencv_.*"/""/g | sed s/"libopencv.*"/""/g | sed s/"-L"/""/g | sed s/" "/""/g)
endif

ifeq ($(OPENMP_ON), Y)
    ifeq ($(UNAME),Darwin)
        CFLAGS += -fopenmp
        CFLAGS  += -I$(HOSTCC_DIR)/include
        LDFLAGS += -L$(HOSTCC_DIR)/lib
        LDFLAGS += -liomp5
        LLVM_LIBRARY_PATH   = $(HOSTCC_DIR)/lib
    else
        CFLAGS += -fopenmp
        LDFLAGS += -lgomp
    endif
endif
LDFLAGS += -lpthread

ALL_CFLAGS :=
ALL_LDFLAGS :=
ifeq ($(GPU_ON), Y)
    ALL_CFLAGS +=  $(NVCCFLAGS)
    ALL_CFLAGS +=  $(addprefix -Xcompiler ,$(CFLAGS))
    ALL_LDFLAGS += $(NVLDFLAGS)
    ALL_LDFLAGS += $(addprefix -Xlinker ,$(LDFLAGS))
else
    ALL_CFLAGS +=  $(CFLAGS)
    ALL_LDFLAGS += $(LDFLAGS)
endif


vpath %.cpp .

INCLUDE  = -I$(INSTALL_DIR)/includes -Iinclude
TARGET   = main
OBJDIR   = ./obj
ifeq "$(strip $(OBJDIR))" ""
    OBJDIR = .
endif

SOURCES  = $(wildcard src/*.cpp) main.cpp #$(TARGET:=.cpp)
OBJECTS  = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
# SRC_DIR = cpp/src  # Or whatever your source directory is
# vpath %.cpp $(SRC_DIR)
# SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
# OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:$(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp=%.o)

# Adjusted vpath for finding source files
vpath %.cpp src


ifeq ($(UNAME),Darwin)
    TEST_ENV_NAME = DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
endif
ifeq ($(UNAME),Linux)
    TEST_ENV_NAME = LD_LIBRARY_PATH
endif

ifeq ($(GPU_ON), Y)
    CUDA_SOURCES  = $(wildcard *.cu)
    OBJECTS  += $(CUDA_SOURCES:.cu=.o)
endif

DEPENDS  = $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)

GOOGLE-PROFILE-LOG = $(TARGET).prof

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)
    $(LINKER) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(ALL_LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CPP) $(ALL_CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@ -c $<

%.o: %.cu
    $(CPP) $(ALL_CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@ -c $<

all: $(TARGET)

test: $(TARGET)
    env $(TEST_ENV_NAME)=$(LLVM_LIBRARY_PATH):$(OPENCV_LIB_DIR):$(MODULE_DIR):$($(TEST_ENV_NAME)) ./$(TARGET) $(FILE_DUMP) $(USE_TEMP_FILE) $(USE_LAST_DERIV_MIN_MAX) $(USE_CUDA) $(NUM_OF_THREADS) $(NUM_OF_GPUS) $(CHUNK_SIZE) $(USE_USER_DEFINED_GPU_DYNSYS_FUNC)

google-prof: $(GOOGLE-PROFILE-LOG)

$(GOOGLE-PROFILE-LOG): $(TARGET)
    env LD_PRELOAD=$(GOOGLE_PERF_LIB):$(LD_PRELOAD) CPUPROFILE=./$(GOOGLE-PROFILE-LOG) CPUPROFILE_FREQUENCY=$(CPUPROFILE_FREQUENCY) $(TEST_ENV_NAME)=$(LLVM_LIBRARY_PATH):$(OPENCV_LIB_DIR):$(MODULE_DIR):$($(TEST_ENV_NAME)) ./$(TARGET) $(FILE_DUMP) $(USE_TEMP_FILE) $(USE_LAST_DERIV_MIN_MAX) $(USE_CUDA) $(NUM_OF_THREADS) $(NUM_OF_GPUS) $(CHUNK_SIZE) $(USE_USER_DEFINED_GPU_DYNSYS_FUNC)

show-google-prof: $(TARGET) $(GOOGLE-PROFILE-LOG)
    google-pprof $(TARGET) $(GOOGLE-PROFILE-LOG) --text

kcachegrind-google-prof: $(GOOGLE-PROFILE-LOG)  $(TARGET)
    google-pprof $(TARGET) --callgrind $(GOOGLE-PROFILE-LOG) > $(GOOGLE-PROFILE-LOG).cg
    kcachegrind $(GOOGLE-PROFILE-LOG).cg &

time: $(TARGET)
    $(TIME) env $(TEST_ENV_NAME)=$(LLVM_LIBRARY_PATH):$(OPENCV_LIB_DIR):$(MODULE_DIR):$($(TEST_ENV_NAME)) ./$(TARGET) $(FILE_DUMP) $(USE_TEMP_FILE) $(USE_LAST_DERIV_MIN_MAX) $(USE_CUDA) $(NUM_OF_THREADS) $(NUM_OF_GPUS) $(CHUNK_SIZE) $(USE_USER_DEFINED_GPU_DYNSYS_FUNC)

time_chunk_sizes: $(TARGET)
    $(TIME) env $(TEST_ENV_NAME)=$(LLVM_LIBRARY_PATH):$(OPENCV_LIB_DIR):$(MODULE_DIR):$($(TEST_ENV_NAME)) ./$(TARGET) $(FILE_DUMP) $(USE_TEMP_FILE) $(USE_LAST_DERIV_MIN_MAX) $(USE_CUDA) $(NUM_OF_THREADS) $(NUM_OF_GPUS) 1 $(USE_USER_DEFINED_GPU_DYNSYS_FUNC)
    $(TIME) env $(TEST_ENV_NAME)=$(LLVM_LIBRARY_PATH):$(OPENCV_LIB_DIR):$(MODULE_DIR):$($(TEST_ENV_NAME)) ./$(TARGET) $(FILE_DUMP) $(USE_TEMP_FILE) $(USE_LAST_DERIV_MIN_MAX) $(USE_CUDA) $(NUM_OF_THREADS) $(NUM_OF_GPUS) 2 $(USE_USER_DEFINED_GPU_DYNSYS_FUNC)
    $(TIME) env $(TEST_ENV_NAME)=$(LLVM_LIBRARY_PATH):$(OPENCV_LIB_DIR):$(MODULE_DIR):$($(TEST_ENV_NAME)) ./$(TARGET) $(FILE_DUMP) $(USE_TEMP_FILE) $(USE_LAST_DERIV_MIN_MAX) $(USE_CUDA) $(NUM_OF_THREADS) $(NUM_OF_GPUS) 4 $(USE_USER_DEFINED_GPU_DYNSYS_FUNC)
    $(TIME) env $(TEST_ENV_NAME)=$(LLVM_LIBRARY_PATH):$(OPENCV_LIB_DIR):$(MODULE_DIR):$($(TEST_ENV_NAME)) ./$(TARGET) $(FILE_DUMP) $(USE_TEMP_FILE) $(USE_LAST_DERIV_MIN_MAX) $(USE_CUDA) $(NUM_OF_THREADS) $(NUM_OF_GPUS) 8 $(USE_USER_DEFINED_GPU_DYNSYS_FUNC)
    $(TIME) env $(TEST_ENV_NAME)=$(LLVM_LIBRARY_PATH):$(OPENCV_LIB_DIR):$(MODULE_DIR):$($(TEST_ENV_NAME)) ./$(TARGET) $(FILE_DUMP) $(USE_TEMP_FILE) $(USE_LAST_DERIV_MIN_MAX) $(USE_CUDA) $(NUM_OF_THREADS) $(NUM_OF_GPUS) 16 $(USE_USER_DEFINED_GPU_DYNSYS_FUNC)
    $(TIME) env $(TEST_ENV_NAME)=$(LLVM_LIBRARY_PATH):$(OPENCV_LIB_DIR):$(MODULE_DIR):$($(TEST_ENV_NAME)) ./$(TARGET) $(FILE_DUMP) $(USE_TEMP_FILE) $(USE_LAST_DERIV_MIN_MAX) $(USE_CUDA) $(NUM_OF_THREADS) $(NUM_OF_GPUS) 32 $(USE_USER_DEFINED_GPU_DYNSYS_FUNC)
    $(TIME) env $(TEST_ENV_NAME)=$(LLVM_LIBRARY_PATH):$(OPENCV_LIB_DIR):$(MODULE_DIR):$($(TEST_ENV_NAME)) ./$(TARGET) $(FILE_DUMP) $(USE_TEMP_FILE) $(USE_LAST_DERIV_MIN_MAX) $(USE_CUDA) $(NUM_OF_THREADS) $(NUM_OF_GPUS) 64 $(USE_USER_DEFINED_GPU_DYNSYS_FUNC)

iprofiler: $(TARGET)
    cp -rp $(OPENCV_LIB_DIR):$(MODULE_DIR)/liblevelset.so .
    cp -rp $(OPENCV_LIB_DIR):$(MODULE_DIR)/libhelperOC.so .
    iprofiler -T 0 -$(TIME)profiler ./$(TARGET) $(FILE_DUMP) $(USE_TEMP_FILE) $(USE_LAST_DERIV_MIN_MAX) $(USE_CUDA) $(NUM_OF_THREADS) $(NUM_OF_GPUS) $(CHUNK_SIZE) $(USE_USER_DEFINED_GPU_DYNSYS_FUNC)
#   rm -rf liblevelset.so
#   rm -rf libhelperOC.so


valgrind: $(TARGET)
    env $(TEST_ENV_NAME)=$(LLVM_LIBRARY_PATH):$(OPENCV_LIB_DIR):$(MODULE_DIR):$($(TEST_ENV_NAME)) valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --track-origins=yes --error-limit=no ./$(TARGET) $(FILE_DUMP) $(USE_TEMP_FILE) $(USE_LAST_DERIV_MIN_MAX) $(USE_CUDA) $(NUM_OF_THREADS) $(NUM_OF_GPUS) $(CHUNK_SIZE) $(USE_USER_DEFINED_GPU_DYNSYS_FUNC)


massif: $(TARGET)
    env $(TEST_ENV_NAME)=$(LLVM_LIBRARY_PATH):$(OPENCV_LIB_DIR):$(MODULE_DIR):$($(TEST_ENV_NAME)) valgrind --tool=massif ./$(TARGET) $(FILE_DUMP) $(USE_TEMP_FILE) $(USE_LAST_DERIV_MIN_MAX) $(USE_CUDA) $(NUM_OF_THREADS) $(NUM_OF_GPUS) $(CHUNK_SIZE) $(USE_USER_DEFINED_GPU_DYNSYS_FUNC)

massif_chunk_sizes: $(TARGET)
    env $(TEST_ENV_NAME)=$(LLVM_LIBRARY_PATH):$(OPENCV_LIB_DIR):$(MODULE_DIR):$($(TEST_ENV_NAME)) valgrind --tool=massif ./$(TARGET) $(FILE_DUMP) $(USE_TEMP_FILE) $(USE_LAST_DERIV_MIN_MAX) $(USE_CUDA) $(NUM_OF_THREADS) $(NUM_OF_GPUS) 1 $(USE_USER_DEFINED_GPU_DYNSYS_FUNC)
    env $(TEST_ENV_NAME)=$(LLVM_LIBRARY_PATH):$(OPENCV_LIB_DIR):$(MODULE_DIR):$($(TEST_ENV_NAME)) valgrind --tool=massif ./$(TARGET) $(FILE_DUMP) $(USE_TEMP_FILE) $(USE_LAST_DERIV_MIN_MAX) $(USE_CUDA) $(NUM_OF_THREADS) $(NUM_OF_GPUS) 2 $(USE_USER_DEFINED_GPU_DYNSYS_FUNC)
    env $(TEST_ENV_NAME)=$(LLVM_LIBRARY_PATH):$(OPENCV_LIB_DIR):$(MODULE_DIR):$($(TEST_ENV_NAME)) valgrind --tool=massif ./$(TARGET) $(FILE_DUMP) $(USE_TEMP_FILE) $(USE_LAST_DERIV_MIN_MAX) $(USE_CUDA) $(NUM_OF_THREADS) $(NUM_OF_GPUS) 4 $(USE_USER_DEFINED_GPU_DYNSYS_FUNC)
    env $(TEST_ENV_NAME)=$(LLVM_LIBRARY_PATH):$(OPENCV_LIB_DIR):$(MODULE_DIR):$($(TEST_ENV_NAME)) valgrind --tool=massif ./$(TARGET) $(FILE_DUMP) $(USE_TEMP_FILE) $(USE_LAST_DERIV_MIN_MAX) $(USE_CUDA) $(NUM_OF_THREADS) $(NUM_OF_GPUS) 8 $(USE_USER_DEFINED_GPU_DYNSYS_FUNC)
    env $(TEST_ENV_NAME)=$(LLVM_LIBRARY_PATH):$(OPENCV_LIB_DIR):$(MODULE_DIR):$($(TEST_ENV_NAME)) valgrind --tool=massif ./$(TARGET) $(FILE_DUMP) $(USE_TEMP_FILE) $(USE_LAST_DERIV_MIN_MAX) $(USE_CUDA) $(NUM_OF_THREADS) $(NUM_OF_GPUS) 16 $(USE_USER_DEFINED_GPU_DYNSYS_FUNC)
    env $(TEST_ENV_NAME)=$(LLVM_LIBRARY_PATH):$(OPENCV_LIB_DIR):$(MODULE_DIR):$($(TEST_ENV_NAME)) valgrind --tool=massif ./$(TARGET) $(FILE_DUMP) $(USE_TEMP_FILE) $(USE_LAST_DERIV_MIN_MAX) $(USE_CUDA) $(NUM_OF_THREADS) $(NUM_OF_GPUS) 32 $(USE_USER_DEFINED_GPU_DYNSYS_FUNC)
    env $(TEST_ENV_NAME)=$(LLVM_LIBRARY_PATH):$(OPENCV_LIB_DIR):$(MODULE_DIR):$($(TEST_ENV_NAME)) valgrind --tool=massif ./$(TARGET) $(FILE_DUMP) $(USE_TEMP_FILE) $(USE_LAST_DERIV_MIN_MAX) $(USE_CUDA) $(NUM_OF_THREADS) $(NUM_OF_GPUS) 64 $(USE_USER_DEFINED_GPU_DYNSYS_FUNC)

helgrind: $(TARGET)
    env $(TEST_ENV_NAME)=$(LLVM_LIBRARY_PATH):$(OPENCV_LIB_DIR):$(MODULE_DIR):$($(TEST_ENV_NAME)) valgrind --tool=helgrind --histroy-level=approx ./$(TARGET) $(FILE_DUMP) $(USE_TEMP_FILE) $(USE_LAST_DERIV_MIN_MAX) $(USE_CUDA) $(NUM_OF_THREADS) $(NUM_OF_GPUS) $(CHUNK_SIZE) $(USE_USER_DEFINED_GPU_DYNSYS_FUNC)


check:
    python checker.py ref_all_loop.csv   all_loop.csv
    python checker.py ref_short_loop.csv short_loop.csv
    python checker.py ref_mid_loop.csv   mid_loop.csv

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR)
    rm -f $(OBJECTS)
    rm -f gmon.out
    rm -f $(TARGET)
    rm -f *.mat
    rm -rf $(GOOGLE-PROFILE-LOG) $(GOOGLE-PROFILE-LOG).cg

cleanlog:
    rm -f gmon.out
    rm -f *.mat
    rm -rf $(GOOGLE-PROFILE-LOG) $(GOOGLE-PROFILE-LOG).cg

-include $(DEPENDS)
```

Now, I certainly am not an expert in `make` but it seems that at the end of the day, the flags for including `OpenCV` while building are exactly the same in the different projects (`CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`, line 161 of the Makefile).

The only difference is that for the full project I get the build warnings

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_highgui.so.4.2, needed by /home/jv/BEACLS/beacls/builds/x86_64/lib/libhelperOC.so, may conflict with libopencv_highgui.so.3.3
    /usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.2, needed by /home/jv/BEACLS/beacls/builds/x86_64/lib/libhelperOC.so, may conflict with libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.3
    /usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_imgproc.so.4.2, needed by /home/jv/BEACLS/beacls/builds/x86_64/lib/libhelperOC.so, may conflict with libopencv_imgproc.so.3.3
    /usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_core.so.4.2, needed by /home/jv/BEACLS/beacls/builds/x86_64/lib/libhelperOC.so, may conflict with libopencv_core.so.3.3
```

but I see no reason why this might have any effect on the runtime as the other `OpenCV` functions such as `imread` and `threshold` work perfectly...

So what exactly causes some openCV functions to work, while it segfaults specifically on one function `findContours`?

What I tried:

1. printed all the make flags to double check if the opencv is included in the build procedure
2. instead of using the matrix (which I need to convert quite a bit), using the image that I use in the little test project
3. checked by `.bashrc` script if there was anything related to opencv (there wasn't)
4. tried to convert the makefile to a CMakeLists.txt build method but this proved to be too difficult for me

Any help would be so much appreciated! I'm at a loss for what to do here. Since I build upon an existing project and there is a significant library associated with the project, I expect you might need more information from me. Please let me know!

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether you've really done this or not but make will print out the compile and link lines that it's using.  Have you compared the compile and link lines printed when your test program builds versus the ones printed by the big makefile?  Investigating what you _think_ might be the case from the makefile is not a great way to start: you should look at the _actual_ output generated by make.  Are there any non-trivial or unexpected differences?  Remember that order of options **CAN** make a huge difference, especially during linking.